# How to regexp search for =, but not >=, ==, <=, !=, ~=, etc. in Emacs?

Tags: regex, emacs

I would like to do regexp search for the `=` character, which may or may not have spaces on either sides, and may be at the beginning or end of a line. I've tried a couple:

- `=` doesn't work because it matches `==`, `>=`, etc.
- `[^<>=]=[^<>=]` doesn't work because it captures the two characters immediately before and after the `=` character, which is undesirable
- I thought `\_<` and `\_>` might be useful but I cannot figure out what these are for

In Vim, there are `\zs` and `\ze` which denote the start and end of a match so that I can match against the surrounding characters only for context. But Emacs doesn't have these.

Is this possible with Emacs?

Comment: Anything is possible in Emacs.

This doesn't work for you?: `[^<>=!~] ?= ?[^=]`. Which command are you using to search?

Comment: @elethan That captures even *more* characters than I want. I'm looking to capture *only* the `=` as I said.

Comment: Ah yes I did read that before but now I understand what you mean. It sounds like you need a negative lookahead or lookbehind, and I think that those are not supported in lisp regexps. At least that is what I remember, but I will look into it when back at a desktop.

Comment: elethan is correct -- there are no Perl-like zero-width look-ahead/behind assertions of that nature in Emacs regexps, so you cannot write a regexp which matches *only* `=` if you also need to assert certain characters either side of it. As Drew says, you'll need to update your question to show us what it is you are trying to do, as the right solution will depend on the context.

Comment: Regarding your question about `\_<` and `\_>`, they are zero-width assertions matching the beginning and end of a *symbol*, where a symbol is a contiguous sequence of *symbol-constituent* or *word-constituent* characters in accordance with the *syntax table* for the buffer in question. There are other similar constructs such as `\<` and `\>` and `\b` (which match word boundaries). I suspect you would need to mess with the syntax table in order for these to be of any help for this question (which just isn't going to be the right solution).

Answer (score 2):

Your question is underspecified.  What characters do you disallow just before and after `=`?  You allow space chars (what about other whitespace?).  But do you allow **only** space chars (or whitespace)?

E.g., do you allow `a=b` to match? If so, then perhaps letters are not disallowed?

Once you specify clearly what chars you allow and disallow immediately before and after `=`, you can write the regexp.  But since you want to "capture" only the `=` in the matching contexts you will need to use a regexp group for the `=` and retrieve only what it matches, after matching everything.

For example, `[ ]*=[ ]*` matches `=` possibly surrounded by space chars. But if you want to capture only the `=` in that context then you need to use `[ ]*\\(=\\)[ ]*` and then use `(match-string 1)` to get the `=`.

You also don't say whether you are matching text in a buffer or in a string.

And you don't say whether you want to do this interactively or from a Lisp program.

The exact code you need depends on these things.  If interactively, e.g., for search, you don't need to double backslashes.  If a string instead of a buffer then you need to pass the string as a second argument to `match-string`.

In general, your question is underspecified, and the answer involves specifying these things - in particular, just what contexts you want to match (what chars are allowed before and after `=`) and what part(s) of the matching contexts you want to retrieve (just the `=` or the `=` plus some of the chars before and after it).